# Email before and after restart of PID - Bash script

Tags: bash, unix

I created a simple script that will list down the top 10 processes if threshold is breached. After listing down the top 10 processes, it will kill -9 the first two PIDs and then send an email as an FYI.

The email contains the list of PIDs before and after the restart. I saved the before and after processes to a txt file for easier tracking.

However, after the PIDs are killed, the "after" PIDs aren't generated because the before and after txt file generates at the same time. So even thought it killed the PIDs, it's not showing the "after" results.

What am I missing?
Here's part of the script:

```
go_send_mail (){

#after restart values

m_after=$tst_gs_dir/tst_memafter.txt
t_after=$tst_gs_dir/tst_topafter.txt

wm_after=$(echo -e "`date` \n $chk" > "$m_after")
wt_after=$(echo -e "`date` \n $top" > "$t_after")
topproc3=$(more "$t_after")
memchk3=$(more "$m_after")

echo -e "Processes
\n Memory check before restart: \n
\n $memchk2
\n \n Top processes before the restart:
\n \n $topproc2 \n
\n Processes after the restart: \n
\n $topproc3 \n
\n Memory check after restart: \n
\n $memchk3 \n \n `date`" | mailx -s "$subject" -r "$mail_from" abc@gmail.com
}

if [[ "$memtst" -le  "$threshold" ]]; then #for testing
echo "Saving previous processes"
sleep 5
#writes results to a file#
topproc=$(echo -e "`date` \n $top" > "$file")
memchk=$(echo -e "`date` \n $chk" > "$file_chk")
topproc2=$(more "$file")
memchk2=$(more "$file_chk")
#restart here
echo "Killing PIDs..."

kill -9 $pid1 $pid2
sleep 2
echo "PIDs killed."
go_send_mail
```

Comment: Please add a shebang and then paste your script at http://www.shellcheck.net/ and try to implement the recommendations made there.

Answer (score 0):

No issue found in shellcheck.net.

What I did to make it work was to create a separate script for the "after" process and call it from the main script.

```
cd $gs_dir

#for testing#
#cd $tst_streams_dir
#cd $tst_gs_dir

##Separate script to write after PID restart is completed##
sh ./procafter.sh
topproc3=$(more "$t_after")
memchk3=$(more "$m_after")
```